# Is there an insulator that becomes metal under higher pressure?

Tags: solid-state-physics

Is there an insulator preferably among elements that becomes metal under higher pressure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several materials, I'm not sure about pure elements though. Among elements, solid oxygen comes to mind. At pressures exceeding 95 GPa, it becomes metallic. At 100 GPa, it even becomes superconducting with a transition temperature of 0.6 K ([doi:10.1038/31656](https://www.nature.com/articles/31656)).

Another material (not an element) is Nickel monoxide which is already solid at room temperature. The insulator-metal transition takes place at a pressure of 240 GPa ([https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.109.086402](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.109.086402))

Comment: Another famous possible example is metallic hydrogen: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metallic_hydrogen

Comment: Silicon goes metallic at 11-12 GPa. Maybe a better question would be "Do all materials necessarily become metals with sufficient pressure?"